# Bootstrap class with css

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a page in which user can track his request process and for this i make a view which is attached as a pic.[image]I want to get tick mark inside the circle . A pic is attached.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
    <li class="">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="1" class="status">

            <h4> FH APPROVAL </h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li complete">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <div class="status">
            <h4>HR APPROVAL </h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li complete">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="status">
            <h4> IT Approval </h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li complete">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="status">
            <h4> Completed </h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
  .timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.status {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.status h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.status:before {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 42%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.li.complete .status {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
}
.li.complete .status:before {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.li.complete .status h4 {
  color: lightgrey;
}

@media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .li {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    display: flex;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .timestamp {
    width: 100px;
  }

  .status:before {
    left: -8%;
    top: 30%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  }
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  color: #758D96;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  border: none;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #75C7F6;
}
```

I tried bootstrap class inside div with "status" class , but it does not working.
I'll appreciate if someone could solve it and replied with snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include font awesome for tick font and add this style

```
.status.add-tick::before {
  padding: 5px;
  content: "\f00c";
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```css
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.li {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.status {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.status:before {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 42%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  content: "";
}

.status.add-tick::before {
  padding: 5px;
  content: "\f00c";
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.li.complete .status {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

.li.complete .status:before {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.li.complete .status h4 {
  color: lightgrey;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  color: #758D96;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  border: none;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #75C7F6;
}

#timeline li {
  width: 25%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  .timeline li h4 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eed659c9d4.js"></script>


<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li class="">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="1" class="status add-tick">

      <h4> FH APPROVAL </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="status">
      <h4>HR APPROVAL </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="status">
      <h4> IT Approval </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Completed </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it possible to make it responsive ? my whole app is responsive except this page and that is because using too much css may be , is ther any way to make it responsive ?

Comment: I tried to give responsive class in div tags but does not work !

Comment: See the updates that i did to your css in my updated answer, the way you are using media queries was wrong, i corrected it, but i didnt like the wrapped up progress bar like you did, I kept the same UI in mobile as well but with reduced widths and font size . Please check if this css and hrtml is responsive on your page, if some issue comes up i will try and fix that too. But you need to send me an image of whats the issue

Comment: Thanks Let me check it

Comment: This is how it appears after your recent changes and i can't scroll down too https://drive.google.com/file/d/13pTuMMGcb6X6BHy8iu_Y-ej1P609_wvO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is how it appears before your recent changes 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13pTuMMGcb6X6BHy8iu_Y-ej1P609_wvO
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UUs_vbc3aE5awXi9Iy5bFcRzxeK70xEO

Comment: Can i see where its working ? its impossible for me to debug why it effected your scrolling of page !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176214/discussion-between-faizan-and-nandita-arora-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

Ok now you just need to add the **active** class to the status to make it work.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.status {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.status.active:before {
  content: "";
  width: 13px;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  z-index: 1;
  top: -7px;
  left: 45%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status h4:before {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 42%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status.active h4:before {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}

.li.complete .status {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

.li.complete .status:before {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.li.complete .status h4 {
  color: lightgrey;
}

@media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .li {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    display: flex;
    width: inherit;
  }
  .timestamp {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .status:before {
    left: -8%;
    top: 30%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  }
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  color: #758D96;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  border: none;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #75C7F6;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li class="">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="1" class="status active">

      <h4> FH APPROVAL </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="status">
      <h4>HR APPROVAL </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="status">
      <h4> IT Approval </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Completed </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```